# Callback method in DLL's COM interface

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have a DLL written in Delphi with COM interface:

```
unit uRestIntf;

interface

type
  TRestoreCallback = procedure(Msg: WideString) stdcall;

  IRestore = interface
  ['{dffe3bc0-d197-4c30-be80-5296a5a10f73}']
    procedure Restore(Id: Integer; CallbackProc: TestoreCallback); safecall;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

CallbackProc should returns me strings with description of restoration proces.
Next I want to show this strings on MassageBox or save to log file.

I want to use this interface in C# code.

I declared interface:

```
[ComImport, Guid("dffe3bc0-d197-4c30-be80-5296a5a10f73"),
            InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

        public interface IGetNewRestoreObject
        {
            [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
            void Restore(int IdFirm, TRestoreCallbackCB cb);
        }
```

```
[DllImport("DelphiRestore.dll")]
        public static extern void GetNewRestoreObject(out IGetNewRestoreObject aGetNewRestoreObject);
```

And in proper method I create Object:

```
GetNewRestoreObject(out lRestoreObject);
```

This works, but I can't use callback from this dll. I don't know how to declare and use callback method in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this
I used IntPtr to callback

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
            void Restore(int IdFirm, IntPtr cb);
```

```
private void CallbackRestoreStatus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string aMess)
        {
            //Do something e.g.: Show Message
        }
```

and next

```
TRestoreCallbackCB SaveStatus = CallbackRestoreStatus;
IntPtr p = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(SaveStatus);
lRestoreObject.Restore(1, p);
GC.KeepAlive(SaveStatus);
```

Works!

Comment: You need to add `GC.KeepAlive(SaveStatus);` on the final line after using the callback, otherwise you risk it getting disposed in an optimized build